# Elastic search filters aggregation with multiple filters in each bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using filters aggregation like so

```
"aggs": {
        "streams": {
            "filters": {
                "filters": {
                    "week1": {
                        'range': {
                            'date': {
                                'gte': start_date1,
                                'lte': end_date1,
                                "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "week2": {
                        'range': {
                            'date': {
                                'gte': start_date2,
                                'lte': end_date2,
                                "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "streamCountAll": {"sum": {"field": "streamCount"}},
                "deviceName": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "deviceName",
                         "size": 30,
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "streamCount": {"sum": {"field": "streamCount"}}
                    }
                },
```

This attempts to find streams for two separate weeks for comparison. Now I want to add version number to the mix.
Instead of week1 vs week2, I am trying to do week1 version A vs week 1 version B.
My query looks like

```
 "aggs": {
        "streams": {
            "filters": {
                "filters": {
                    "week1": {
                        'terms' : {'version': [109, 107]},
                        'range': {
                            'date': {
                                'gte': start_date1,
                                'lte': end_date1,
                                "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "week2": {
                        'range': {
                            'date': {
                                'gte': start_date2,
                                'lte': end_date2,
                                "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "streamCountAll": {"sum": {"field": "streamCount"}}
```

However I am getting an error "reason": "No query registered for [version]"

Can any one help me out here, with adding multiple criteria into the filters aggregation buckets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bring a `bool/filter` query into the mix like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "streams": {
        "filters": {
            "filters": {
                "week1": {
                    "bool": { 
                        "filter": [
                            { 'terms' : {'version': [109, 107]}}, 
                            { 'range': {
                                'date': {
                                    'gte': start_date1,
                                    'lte': end_date1,
                                    "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "week2": {
                    "bool": { 
                        "filter": [
                            { 'terms' : {'version': [110, 108]}}, 
                            { 'range': {
                                'date': {
                                    'gte': start_date2,
                                    'lte': end_date2,
                                    "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "streamCountAll": {"sum": {"field": "streamCount"}}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm..
Tried up voting, but I can't do that yet!!

Update: Marked as accepted answer.